# Meteor & mongoDB LIKE query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Im trying to produce a query from what the user has searched for. I have an array of strings which i just want to send through in the mongoDB selector, my problem is with the /text/ syntax, it works perfectly from the mongoDB console like this:

```
Items.find({ $or: [{name: /doc/}, {tags: /doc/}, {name: /test/}, {tags: /test/}] });
```

But i cannot manage to write the same syntax in javascript, i've tried several version.

```
var mongoDbArr = [];
  searchArray.forEach(function(text) {
    mongoDbArr.push({name: /text/});
    mongoDbArr.push({tags: /text/});
  });
  return Items.find({ $or: mongoDbArr});
```

But it only searches for "text" and not whats in the variable. And like this:

```
var mongoDbArr = [];
  searchArray.forEach(function(text) {
    mongoDbArr.push({name: "/" + text + "/"});
    mongoDbArr.push({tags: "/" + text + "/"});
  });
  return Items.find({ $or: mongoDbArr});
```

But that doesn't give me any results back. What am i missing?

Comment: Do you use mongodb on the server, or minimongo on the client? (or both?)

Comment: Right now, both. Im just trying an app with Meteor default settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to build your regular expressions with javascript:

```
var mongoDbArr = [];
searchArray.forEach(function(text) {
    mongoDbArr.push({name: new RegExp(text)});
    mongoDbArr.push({tags: new RegExp(text,"i")});
});

return Items.find({ $or: mongoDbArr});
```

Or use a [regular expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) query with mongodb:

```
mongoDbArr.push({name: { $regex : text, $options:"i" } });
mongoDbArr.push({tags: { $regex : text, $options:"i" } });
```

To escape special characters you can do this before you use `text` (from JQuery UI's source)

```
text = text.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

Comment: Regular expression worked for now, im worried what happens when the user enters reserved characters that means different things in regex.

Comment: Ive modified the answer to escape special characters.

Comment: Whoa. Do both of these regex queries work client side? Wow. Yes, it does. Mind blown. Putting this in my new [Meteor autocompletion](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete) package...

Comment: This was a great help. Was stuck on the exact same kind of query issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this in the publish function in the server:

```
return YourCollection.find({'$or' : [ 
  { 'field1':{'$regex':searchString} },
  { 'field2':{'$regex':searchString} },
  { 'field3':{'$regex':searchString} }, ]
});
```